# Find Last modified timestamp of a files/folders in Azure Datalake through python script in Azure databricks that uses Credential passthrough

Tags: pyspark, azure-data-lake, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I have an Azure DataLake Storage Gen2 which contains a few Parquet files. My Organization has enabled credential passthrough and so I am able to create a python script in Azure Databricks and access the files available in ADLS using dbutils.fs.ls. All these work fine.

Now, I need to access the last modified timestamp of these files too. I found a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58237338/how-to-get-the-last-modification-time-of-each-files-present-in-azure-datalake-st) that does this. However, it uses BlockBlobService and requires an account_key.

I do not have an account key and can't get one due to security policies of the organization. I am unsure of how to do the same using Credential passthrough. Any ideas here?

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/credential-passthrough/adls-passthrough?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to mount the Azure DataLake Storage Gen2 instance with credentials passthrough.

```py
    configs = {
      "fs.azure.account.auth.type": "CustomAccessToken",
      "fs.azure.account.custom.token.provider.class":   spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.passthrough.adls.gen2.tokenProviderClassName")
    }
    mount_name = 'localmountname'
    container_name = 'containername'
    storage_account_name = 'datalakestoragename'
    dbutils.fs.mount(
      source = f"abfss://{container_name}@{storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/",
      mount_point = f"/mnt/{mount_name}>",
      extra_configs = configs)
```

Comment: Hi Axel - Thank you for your help. I am able to access my mounted drive but only via dbutils.fs.ls(<MyMountDrive>). Via this, I am unable to find the last modified timestamp and hence stuck in the same problem again. 

I still cannot find a way to access the mounted drive via ls command to read the last modified timestamp. Any ideas here??

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the Hadoop FileSystem object accessible via Spark:

```
import time

path = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
fs = path('abfss://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/').getFileSystem(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())

res = fs.listFiles(path('abfss://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/path'), True)

while res.hasNext():
  file = res.next()
  localTime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(file.getModificationTime() / 1000))
  print(f"{file.getPath()}: {localTime}")
```

Note that that the `True` parameter in the `listFiles()` method means recursive.