# How to efficiently read the data lake files' metadata

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I want to read the last modified datetime of the files in data lake in a databricks script. If I could read it efficiently as a column when reading data from data lake, it would be perfect.
Thank you:)

[image]

**UPDATE**:
If you're working in Databricks, since Databricks runtime 10.4 released on Mar 18, 2022, dbutils.fs.ls() command returns “modificationTime” of the folders and files as well:
[image]

Comment: will this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61317600/how-to-get-files-metadata-when-retrieving-data-from-hdfs/61423874#61423874 ?

Comment: @Srinivas Thank you for your comment. I'm limited to using pyspark and the dbutils.fs.ls which gives out some metadata about files doesn't contain last modified datetime only file size and path. Do you happen to know how I can replicate your logic in pyspark?

Comment: see the linked answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code

```
URI = sc._gateway.jvm.java.net.URI
Path = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
FileSystem = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
conf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()

conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key.<account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net",
  "<account-access-key>")

fs = Path('abfss://<container-name>@<account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<file-path>/').getFileSystem(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())

status=fs.listStatus(Path('abfss://<container-name>@<account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<file-path>/'))

for i in status:
  print(i)
  print(i.getModificationTime())
```

[image]

Comment: If you're working in Databricks, since Databricks runtime 10.4 released on Mar 18, 2022, dbutils.fs.ls() command returns “modificationTime” of the folders and files as well.

Answer (score 1):

We can get those details using a Python code as we don't have direct method to get the modified time and date of the files in data lake

Here is the code

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
from datetime import datetime
import os.path

block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='account-name', account_key='account-key')
container_name ='container-firstname'
second_conatainer_name ='container-Second'
#block_blob_service.create_container(container_name)
generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs(container_name,prefix="Recovery/")
report_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


for blob in generator:
    length = BlockBlobService.get_blob_properties(block_blob_service,container_name,blob.name).properties.content_length
    last_modified = BlockBlobService.get_blob_properties(block_blob_service,container_name,blob.name).properties.last_modified
    file_size = BlockBlobService.get_blob_properties(block_blob_service,container_name,blob.name).properties.content_length
    line = container_name+'|'+second_conatainer_name+'|'+blob.name+'|'+ str(file_size) +'|'+str(last_modified)+'|'+str(report_time)
    print(line)
```

[image]

For more details, refer to the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58237338/how-to-get-the-last-modification-time-of-each-files-present-in-azure-datalake-st) thread which addressing similar issue.

Comment: If you're working in Databricks, since Databricks runtime 10.4 released on Mar 18, 2022, dbutils.fs.ls() command returns “modificationTime” of the folders and files as well.